# How to make Fabric ignore offline hosts in the env.hosts list?

Tags: python, fabric

This is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956717/how-to-make-fabric-execution-follow-the-env-hosts-list-order), but a different one.

I have the following fabfile:

```
from fabric.api import *

host1 = '192.168.200.181'
offline_host2 = '192.168.200.199'
host3 = '192.168.200.183'

env.hosts = [host1, offline_host2, host3]
env.warn_only = True

def df_h():
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        run("df -h | grep sda3")
```

And the output is:

```
[192.168.200.199] run: df -h | grep sda3

Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host 192.168.200.199: No route to host

Aborting.
```

After the execution hits the offline server, it aborts immediately, regardless of the other servers in the env.hosts list.

I have used the env setting "warn_only=True", but maybe I'm using it improperly.

How can I modify this behavior so that it will only prints the error and continue executing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [Fabric documentation on warn_only](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/usage/env.html#warn-only),

> `env.warn_only` "specifies whether or not to warn, instead of abort, when `run`/`sudo`/`local` encounter error conditions.

This will not help in the case of a server being down, since the failure occurs during the SSH attempt before executing `run`/`sudo`/`local`.

One solution would be to create a function to check if each server is up prior to executing your tasks. Below is the code that I used.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from fabric.api import run, sudo, local, env
import paramiko
import socket

host1 = '192.168.200.181'
offline_host2 = '192.168.200.199'
host3 = '192.168.200.183'

env.hosts = [host1, offline_host2, host3]

def df_h():
    if _is_host_up(env.host, int(env.port)) is True:
        run("df -h | grep sda1")


def _is_host_up(host, port):
    # Set the timeout
    original_timeout = socket.getdefaulttimeout()
    new_timeout = 3
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(new_timeout)
    host_status = False
    try:
        transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
        host_status = True
    except:
        print('***Warning*** Host {host} on port {port} is down.'.format(
            host=host, port=port)
        )
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(original_timeout)
    return host_status
```

Comment: I've used a similar way to do this, but much naive -- I wrapped ping command with subprocess module -_-"   
I should definitely look more into the modules you've used. Thanks, man.

Comment: @jevonearth's answer suggests the fabric >=v1.4  way of doing by using the --skip-bad-hosts flag or env.skip_bad_hosts = True in the function.

Answer (score 21):

As of version 1.4 Fabric has a `--skip-bad-hosts` option that can be set from the command line, or by setting the variable in your fab file.

```
env.skip_bad_hosts = True
```

Documentation for the option is here:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/fab.html#cmdoption--skip-bad-hosts

Don't forget to explicitly set the timeout value also.

Comment: This answer is the correct one for fabric >=v1.4 and needs to be upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You're not using it improperly.  You can even just provide `--warn-only=true` on the command line.  [It's the documented method suggested by the development team.](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-w)

Comment: The parameter should be "--warn-only". However, run "fab --warn-only df_h" outputs the same error message. Looks like connection failure is not covered by the "warn_only" setting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Matthew's answer, I came up with a decorator that accomplishes just that:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from paramiko import Transport
from socket import getdefaulttimeout, setdefaulttimeout
from fabric.api import run, cd, env, roles


roledefs = {
    'greece': [
        'alpha',
        'beta'
    ],
    'arabia': [
        'kha',
        'saad'
    ]
}

env.roledefs = roledefs


def if_host_offline_ignore(fn):
    def wrapped():
        original_timeout = getdefaulttimeout()
        setdefaulttimeout(3)
        try:
            Transport((env.host, int(env.port)))
            return fn()
        except:
            print "The following host appears to be offline: " + env.host
        setdefaulttimeout(original_timeout)
    return wrapped


@roles('greece')
@if_host_offline_ignore
def hello_greece():
    with cd("/tmp"):
        run("touch hello_greece")


@roles('arabia')
@if_host_offline_ignore
def hello_arabia():
    with cd("/tmp"):
        run("touch hello_arabia")
```

It is especially useful when you have multiple hosts and roles.