# How to continue a task when Fabric receives an error

Tags: python, fabric

When I define a task to run on several remote servers, if the task runs on server one and exits with an error, Fabric will stop and abort the task. But I want to make fabric ignore the error and run the task on the next server. How can I make it do this?

For example:

```
$ fab site1_service_gw
[site1rpt1] Executing task 'site1_service_gw'

[site1fep1] run: echo 'Nm123!@#' | sudo -S route
[site1fep1] err:
[site1fep1] err: We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
[site1fep1] err: Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
[site1fep1] err:
[site1fep1] err:     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
[site1fep1] err:     #2) Think before you type.
[site1fep1] err:     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
[site1fep1] err: root's password:
[site1fep1] err: sudo: route: command not found

Fatal error: run() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'echo 'Nm123!@#' | sudo -S route '

Aborting.
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

From [the docs](http://fabric-docs.readthedocs.org/en/1.14/usage/execution.html#failure-handling):

> ... Fabric defaults to a “fail-fast” behavior pattern: if anything goes wrong, such as a remote program returning a nonzero return value or your fabfile’s Python code encountering an exception, execution will halt immediately.
>
> This is typically the desired behavior, but there are many exceptions to the rule, so Fabric provides env.warn_only, a Boolean setting. It defaults to False, meaning an error condition will result in the program aborting immediately. However, if env.warn_only is set to True at the time of failure – with, say, the settings context manager – Fabric will emit a warning message but continue executing.

Looks like you can exercise fine-grained control over where errors are ignored by using the [`settings` context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings), something like so:

```
from fabric.api import settings

sudo('mkdir tmp') # can't fail
with settings(warn_only=True):
    sudo('touch tmp/test') # can fail
sudo('rm tmp') # can't fail
```

Comment: Do not forget to import `from fabric.api settings`

Answer (score 31):

As of Fabric 1.5, there is a ContextManager that makes this easier:

```
from fabric.api import sudo, warn_only

with warn_only():
    sudo('mkdir foo')
```

Update: I re-confirmed that this works in ipython using the following code.

```
from fabric.api import local, warn_only

#aborted with SystemExit after 'bad command'
local('bad command'); local('bad command 2')

#executes both commands, printing errors for each
with warn_only():
    local('bad command'); local('bad command 2')
```

Comment: Which version of fabric are you using? I just retested with Fabric==1.6.2, and it works fine.

Comment: Possibly, I am using Fabric==1.9.0 and it does not work for me

Comment: Just tested on 1.9.0 too. What is your output when you try the example code from my updated comment?

Comment: If you don't want to print the warnings/errors, you can also use the [hide](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.hide) context manager: `with hide('everything'):`

Answer (score 13):

You can also set the entire script's warn_only setting to be true with

```
def local():
    env.warn_only = True
```

Answer (score 11):

You should set the `abort_exception` environment variable and catch the exception.

For example:

```
from fabric.api        import env
from fabric.operations import sudo

class FabricException(Exception):
    pass

env.abort_exception = FabricException
# ... set up the rest of the environment...

try:
    sudo('reboot')
except FabricException:
    pass  # This is expected, we can continue.
```

You can also set it in a with block. See the documentation [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html#abort-exception).

Comment: Thanks for this, but one question - is it possible access/pass in the current fabric env dict as-defined when the exception occurred? (So I can print some specific settings with the exception.)

Comment: @Brian: Couldn't you just check the `fabric.api.env` within your `except` block?

Comment: @ArtOfWarefare Ahh silly me I was trying to avoid wrapping all my tasks in a try/except and instead just set up the `env.abort_exception=MyException` so I could run my own fail. It sort of "works" if I use a function instead of a class (satisfies the callable req for `abort_exception`) but I'm still working on some other issues with that approach.

Comment: @Brian: So inside the body of that function check what `fabric.api.env` is.

Answer (score 11):

In *Fabric 2.x* you can just use *[invoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/)*'s *[run](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/api/__init__.html#invoke.run)* with the *warn=True* argument. Anyway, *invoke* is a dependency of *Fabric 2.x*:

```
from invoke import run
run('bad command', warn=True)
```

From within a task:

```
from invoke import task

@task
def my_task(c):
    c.run('bad command', warn=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

In Fabric 1.3.2 at least, you can recover the exception by catching the `SystemExit` exception. That's helpful if you have more than one command to run in a batch (like a deploy) and want to cleanup if one of them fails.

Comment: +1: Tested - this also works in Fabric 1.9.0. After catching this, you can check the `SystemExit`'s message or code for more details.

Comment: Even better than catching `SystemExit`, set `abort_exception` to a different exception, so that you don't accidentally catch exceptions which have nothing to do with Fabric. See my answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27990242/901641

Answer (score -5):

In my case, on Fabric >= 1.4 [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23139054/1238957) was the correct one.

You can skip bad hosts by adding this:

```
env.skip_bad_hosts = True
```

Or passing the `--skip-bad-hosts` flag/