# Can I catch error codes when using Fabric to run() calls in a remote shell?

Tags: python, error-handling, fabric

Normally Fabric quits as soon as a run() call returns a non-zero exit code. For some calls, however, this is expected. For example, PNGOut returns an error code of 2 when it is unable to compress a file.

Currently I can only circumvent this limitation by either using shell logic (`do_something_that_fails || true` or `do_something_that_fails || do_something_else`), but I'd rather be able to keep my logic in plain Python (as is the Fabric promise).

Is there a way to check for an error code and react to it rather than having Fabric panic and die? I still want the default behaviours for other calls, so changing its behaviour by modifying the environment doesn't seem like a good option (and as far as I recall, you can only use that to tell it to warn instead of dying anyway).

Comment: Before someone marks this a duplicate: [this question is related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876936/how-to-continue-the-task-when-fabric-meet-an-error), but as I said, I want to _react_ to errors, not ignore them.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is dated. Since July 2013, there's been an environment variable that allows you to specify which exception should be raised when an error occurs (the default is a `SystemExit`, which isn't a descendant of Exception which is why it generally causes your program to crash). See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25293275/901641

Comment: // , I'm curious how Invoke would handle this.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can prevent aborting on non-zero exit codes by using the `settings` context manager and the `warn_only` setting:

```
from fabric.api import settings

with settings(warn_only=True):
    result = run('pngout old.png new.png')
    if result.return_code == 0: 
        do something
    elif result.return_code == 2: 
        do something else 
    else: #print error to user
        print result
        raise SystemExit()
```

**Update:** My answer is outdated. See comments below.

Comment: You don't even need to check the return_code, the value of result evaluates as boolean true or false depending on the success state of the task.http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run

Comment: This doesn't work for timeout errors. With or without the "with settings" or even with a try/except, Fabric still exits completely.

Comment: -1: This answer is dated - since July 2013 it's been possible to specify which exception is called when an error is called. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25293275/901641

Comment: I fixed the Python indentation, but now I can't remove the extra text I added to get the edit to apply.

Comment: You can alse use `result.succeeded` and `result.failed`. Beware of evaluating directly `bool(result)` because it uses the output, so in conjunction with `hide("warnings")` and similar, will not be able to tell a success from a failure.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you can. Just change the environment's `abort_exception`. For example:

```
from fabric.api import settings

class FabricException(Exception):
    pass

with settings(abort_exception = FabricException):
    try:
        run(<something that might fail>)
    except FabricException:
        <handle the exception>
```

The documentation on `abort_exception` is [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html#abort-exception).

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide access to the command's exit code, though.

Comment: @AlanPlum - You can get the exception message... but you're right, I don't see a way of getting the exit code.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently messing with the environment *is* the answer.

`fabric.api.settings` can be used as a context manager (with `with`) to apply it to individual statements. The return value of `run()`, `local()` and `sudo()` calls isn't just the output of the shell command, but also has special properties (`return_code` and `failed`) that allow reacting to the errors.

I guess I was looking for something closer to the behaviour of `subprocess.Popen` or Python's usual exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
from fabric.api import run, env
env.warn_only = True # if you want to ignore exceptions and handle them yurself

command = "your command"
x = run(command, capture=True) # run or local or sudo
if(x.stderr != ""):
    error = "On %s: %s" %(command, x.stderr)
    print error
    print x.return_code # which may be 1 or 2
    # do what you want or
    raise Exception(error) #optional
else:
    print "the output of %s is: %s" %(command, x)
    print x.return_code # which is 0
```

Comment: I tried the above with the following result: `TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture'` with Fabric 1.10.2 and Paramiko 1.15.2.

Comment: `capture=True` works only for `local(command, capture=True)`