# python exception handling is not working with fabric.api

Tags: python, vagrant, fabric

I am working on a code so that it can handle the error from `fabric.local`, but some how it always abort with the error and never go into `except` block.
Here is my code, hopefully can get some idea from you guys

This snippet is trying to get Vagrant ssh port, if the vagrant is not up, bring it up

```
def findsshport():
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        try:
            print 'greping port'
            return (local('vagrant ssh-config {} | grep Port'.format(env.vmId), capture=True))
        except:
            print 'vagrant not up'
            with lcd('%s' % (buildfolder)):
                local('vagrant up ext4')
            return (local('vagrant ssh-config {} | grep Port'.format(env.vmId), capture=True))

env.user = 'root'
sshPort = findsshport()
env.hosts = ['127.0.0.1:' + sshPort.split()[1]]
```

Error

```
[localhost] local: vagrant ssh-config 22921a7 | grep Port

Warning: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'vagrant ssh-config 22921a7 | grep Port'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/testing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test123/fabriclogin.py", line 114, in sshlogin
    env.hosts = ['127.0.0.1:' + sshPort.split()[1]]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

**UPDATE**
Similar Question and Answer

[Can I catch error codes when using Fabric to run() calls in a remote shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888568/can-i-catch-error-codes-when-using-fabric-to-run-calls-in-a-remote-shell)

Comment: Please include the full error stack trace.

Comment: Aren't you specifically suppressing the exception with `warn_only=True`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's just a warning from fabric. My understand if you encounter an error on ssh, it doesn't "translate" into a Python error, that's why the exception block doesn't work. Please provide error trace for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Martin is correct, that was a warning from `fabric.api.local` and python exception handling will not treat it as an error. Instead, the error that I seen was from another part of code which the above snippet had returned something invalid.
Instead of using `try` and `except`, `if else` is used with `return_code` which checking the command exit status.

```
port = local('vagrant ssh-config {} | grep Port'.format(env.vmId), capture=True)
if port.return_code == 0:
    return port
else:
    with lcd('%s' % (buildfolder)):
            local('vagrant up {}'.format(env.vmId), capture=True)
        return (local('vagrant ssh-config {} | grep Port'.format(env.vmId), capture=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably here.

```
with settings(warn_only=True)
```

Remove this line, and your local call will raise exceptions if the command exits with a non-zero return code.

```
def task_name():
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        try:
            local("invalid_command")
        except:
            print("This will never print!")
```

Lets compare that to;

```
def task_name():
    try:
        local("invalid_command")
    except:
        print("This will print")
```

Comment: No, comment out `warn_only=True` wouldn't help, it still never go into `except` block. I have updated more complete code and the Traceback. With or without `warn_only=True` getting the same error.