# Run commit only if there are any changes in mercurial

Tags: python, bash, mercurial, fabric

I have the same problem as a guy asking this question: [How to git commit nothing without an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123674/how-to-git-commit-nothing-without-an-error) 
Basically I need to run hg commit, only if there are any changes in my repository. I am using fabric to run the commit, so if there are no changes, it will output a nasty error.

```
local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'hg commit...'
```

This is the answer from aforementioned thread:

```
git add -A
git diff --quiet --exit-code --cached || git commit -m 'bla'
```

It works for git, however I use Merucrial. I have no idea how to do it in Mercurial.

Comment: Can't you parse the result of `hg status` first to see if there are any changes?

Comment: Or run `hg identify` and see if the changeset has a `+` after the changeset id?

Comment: can you read the output of other hg command? like hg st, hg diff? if they return empty, there is no changes

Comment: @koopajah I think that's maybe the only way how to do it. So your comment is nearly the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as koopajah and Kent sugested in comments, I can use the output of `hg status` or `hg diff` to see if there are any changes.
Fabric alows me to read output with `capture=True` flag.

```
if local('hg status', capture=True):
    local('hg commit')
```

Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Going from Tyler Eaves' answer on the page you linked to in your question (and not knowing Fabric), could you do the following:

```
with hide('warnings'):
  with settings(warn_only=True):
    run('hg commit -q ...')
```

The commit, if there is one, will be quiet, so won't report if there are no files committed.  It won't report if there *are* files committed either, which may not be what you want :)

Comment: does not help. `hg commit` exit-code != 0, if commit none **with any options**. Fabric expect zero as exit code for "all OK"

Comment: Yes, as per the help it will return 1 as an exit code, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3877312/218597) suggests that the non-zero return in this instance will be treated as a warning rather than an error, and so should not exit the script. In theory :)