# python fabric with dynamic hosts/servers

Tags: python, deployment, web-deployment, fabric

We have our deployment script with fabric, and it has a list of hosts:

```
 env.hosts = ['services', 'w1zA', 'w1zB']
```

but we have 2 more servers that are on and off when there is more pressure.

So I want my hosts variable to be:

```
 env.hosts = ['services', 'w1zA', 'w1zB', 'w2zA', 'w2zB']
```

but now when I run the script when the extra servers are off,
the deployment fails because it can't connect to those servers.

How can I skip failures if server is off?

Comment: I think this is about `warn_only` setting, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876936/how-to-continue-a-task-when-fabric-receives-an-error.

Comment: yes I saw that... but I don't want to not fail on any reason, only where server is not live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `env.skip_bad_hosts = True` option.

Here is documentation about it: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html#skip-bad-hosts