# Fabric python not generating full output and aborting in middle

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying fabric to fetch few inputs from cisco Nexus switch and output displaying disconnecting with error

error:

```
  c:\Python27>Scripts\fab.exe -f D:\Python-scripts\nexus-fabric.py sh  -H     10.10.10.10 -u admin
  [10.10.10.10] Executing task 'sh'
  [10.10.10.10] run: terminal length 0
  [10.10.10.10] Login password for 'admin':
  [10.10.10.10] out: gl_set_term_size: NULL arguments(s).
  [10.10.10.10] out:

  [10.10.10.10] run: show interface brief
  [10.10.10.10] out:
  [10.10.10.10] out: -------------------------------------------------------   ------------------------
  [10.10.10.10] out: Interface  Vsan   Admin  Admin   Status          SFP         Oper  Oper   Port
  [10.10.10.10] out:                   Mode   Trunk                            Mode  Speed  Channel
  [10.10.10.10] out:                          Mode                                 (Gbps)
 [10.10.10.10] out: -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [10.10.10.10] out: fc2/1      4094   auto   on      sfpAbsent        --     --           --
 [10.10.10.10] out:


 Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code -1 while executing!

 Requested: show interface brief
 Executed: show interface brief

 Aborting.
 Disconnecting from 10.10.10.10... done.
```

code:

```
  from fabric.api import run
  def sh():
     run("terminal length 0",shell=False)
     run("show interface brief",shell=False
```

I used Pass option still it is failing:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import settings
from fabric.api import warn_only
def sh():
    try:
       run("show running-config",shell=False)
       run("show interface brief",shell=False)
    except:
       pass
```

If we run one command i used get output without issues but if i use two run commands second command is terminating with below error

Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code -1 while executing!

I have tried exception as suggested but i am getting below is code and error:

```
from fabric.api        import env,run
from fabric.operations import sudo

class FabricException(Exception):
   pass

env.abort_exception = FabricException
# ... set up the rest of the environment...

def sh():
    try:
       run("show interface brief",shell=False)
       run("show running-config",shell=False)
    except FabricException:
        pass  # This is expected, we can continue.
```

If
Please help

Fabric version :

```
     c:\Python27>Scripts\fab.exe --version
     Fabric 1.13.1
     Paramiko 2.1.2
```

Python 2.7

please help

Comment: What happens when you ssh into server and type failing command manually? After the command, you can also type `echo $?` to see the exit code, that would be helpful if you can provide that too.

Comment: This is network device so cant use echo $? command and I done manually ssh to switch and execute above command and it is working fine, meaning able to see full out.

Comment: Okay, what about the output of the manual typing? Is it showing only single interface or more? I think you are already happy with output of the command, you probably mean rest is not executed?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

As Cisco routers are not plain unix, Fabric won't work reliably on such systems. See [this](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1546) github issue for further details.

**Old answer**:

Fabric runs in fast-fail behavior as default, that is both stated in [doc](http://fabric-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/execution.html#failure-handling) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877312/1233686). I see your command is not critical and you use it mostly for inspection purposes, then you might ignore the exit code by wrapping it as follows:

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
    run("show interface brief",shell=False)
```

That will skip the line even command ends with non-zero return. Finally, you would need following import statement to make `with` block work:

```
from fabric.api import settings
```

**Update**

To completely ignore any failure during the command without using any settings wrapper:

```
try:
    run("show interface brief",shell=False)
except:
    pass
```

**Update 2 (with exception class)**

Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990242/1233686):

```
from fabric.api        import env
from fabric.operations import sudo

class FabricException(Exception):
    pass

env.abort_exception = FabricException
# ... set up the rest of the environment...

def sh():
    try:
        run("show interface brief",shell=False)
    except FabricException:
        pass  # This is expected, we can continue.
```

Comment: Still having same issue.from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import settings
def shrun():
     with settings(warn_only=True):
         run("show running-config",shell=False)
def shint():
     with settings(warn_only=True):
         run("show interface brief",shell=False)

Comment: If i use only single run then it will work and if i use two runs second run is failing .

Comment: Could you add try/except I have updated in answer, which is an overkill but at least should get it done.

Comment: Still failing with pass option and added my script in question

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade fabric to 1.3.4 at least and try `warn_only` or exception handling again? As well as this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27990242/1233686).

Comment: I am using latest 1.13.1

Comment: Oh sorry just noticed you have higher, did setting an exception class work? Lasty, you might try running fab command with `-w` option, or downgrade.

Comment: with option -w is also same error. Could you please guide the exception class?

Comment: I just added as update 2, it is weird there is nothing left to ignore the failure. Trying a smaller major version of fabric maybe?

Comment: if you have added `.. import *` you should remove it and make explicit imports instead, as stated in reddit thread [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2zj3gl/fabric_it_will_not_read_my_defined_hosts_no_hosts/).

Comment: still same issue i imported settings, run and other than this anything i should have to import and i have update code in my question

Comment: `with settings(abort_exception = FabricException):` this look excessive anyway, I didn't have that. Are you sure your last code runs under a function like `def sh():` as in your earlier attempt?

Comment: def sh code slightly i changed edited quetion and i am sure that is running and 1st run successful and second run failed. I am wonder any command you put at first it will work with exception pass  second command fails

Comment: Your last example is not under `def sh():` or `def conf():`, you should edit again.  I have added `def sh():` to **update 2** in my answer.

Comment: sorry i just able to run but still failing second  command and any other way to fix or its bug kind?

Comment: Well it could be a bug with windows if nothing makes it continue, I would try running this from a linux machine (copy/paste code there) to prove then would open a github ticket if it works.

Comment: Then it might be still fabric/paramiko bug, I think this goes to github. You can refer stackoverflow question link there, so they can see what you tried already.

Comment: hi hurturk, where do we need to log bug? do you have link please